# MSSQL finding how many '\'s are in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called 'path' in my table which could look similar to:

\server\directory\subdirectory
\server\directory\subdirectory\subdirectory

I'm trying to write a query that will only bring up entries that have, say at least 0-4 \'s and no more.

I can't seem to figure it out, I though something like:

`SELECT Path FROM Share_table where CHARINDEX('\',path) < 5`

But I have no success with the above line...Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\` with empty string and find the difference with total length. Here is one way

```
where len(path) - len(replace(path,'\','')) < 5
```

Comment: Very clever and elegant!

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much!